# Drupal, elements with odd or even id numbers in view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to have two sliders on my site with the same content.

Could somebody tell me is this possible to create html list with only even or odd elements?

Regards

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "sliders", and I'm unsure why you want to only show even elements in a list?

Comment: @john ... I think he is referring to some views plugin (he refers to views in the title of the question). He wants 2 sliders (there is a typo in his question and he has written "to" instead of "two")

Comment: Yes my bad, I mean two ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have odd and even? What if you have 10 items. The first 5 items you can show in the first view and the next 5 you can show in the second view...

If this is okay for you then you make view 1. Lets say the number of items is set as 5 (under `items to display`). The second view will be exactly the same as second view except that in `items to display` you should set the `offset` to 5. This will skip the first 5 items and show the next 5. So this way you will be able to make 2 sliders